# Deploying a Magento Store from a live server to XAMPP/WAMP

Tags: wamp, xampp

Hi so I need to make some drastic changes to my live site and it looks like I'll have to take it local to make these changes using XAMPP or WAMP.

So far I have taken all of the files from my server and got `myself a database backup via the Magento admin`.

I have now put all the files into a folder within my htdocs and i'm not sure what I do from here?

I am having trouble understanding the database, because I obviously need to add it to XAMPP to get all of my store running how it should however I have no idea how I assign the folder that contains my store the database.

Also what other steps are there?

I have taken a look around Google and I cant seem to find a way of taking a live site and making it local.

**Could someone possibly describe the steps of doing this using XAMPP or WAMP?**

Comment: http://www.grayboxpdx.com/blog/post/setting-up-a-magento-site-on-your-local-machine

Answer (score 2):

This YouTube tutorial might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOIzGpXCuT4

Once you've copied all the files to your local `htdocs` folder, I believe you'll need to migrate your `MySQL database` from your live to your local. Additionally, make sure to update the `web/unsecure/base_url` and 'web/secure/base_url' in the `core_config_data` table.

Comment: And assuming you aren't using credentials from your production database, edit app/etc and modify local.xml to change the database user, name, password and so on.